# Mostrar una ventana Modal (boostrap) desde una función js

Tags: asp.net, modal

Buen día!

Soy un desarrollardor Jr. y es mi primera vez por aqui de antemano disculpas. Mi problema es el siguiente:

**Tengo la siguiente ventana modal de Boostrap**

```
<%--Ventana Modal--%>
<div class="modal fade" id="mEliminar" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLiveLabel" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLiveLabel">Elimiar Registro</h5>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <p>¿Desea eliminar el registro seleccionado?</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" >Si</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

**y un botón**

```
<asp:Button ID="btnEliminar" runat="server" Text="Eliminar" CssClass="btn btn-danger" OnClientClick="return showModal();" CommandName="Eliminar" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("Cedula") %>' />
```

Este botón tiene un OnClientClick que llama a una funcion JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showModal() {

        $('#mEliminar').modal('show');
        return false;


    }
</script>
```

Mi problema es que cuando presiono el botón "Eliminar" y la ventana modal se abre no muestra el modal-body del modal, tan solo el marco y los botones si - no.

Comment: cual es la diferencia entre onclick y onclientclick? (en asp), intentaste solo con el onclick?, disculpa mi ignorancia pero me entro esa duda.

Comment: Somos dos ignorantes!! Jajaja, entiendo que el OnClientClick() me permite ejecutar un script del lado del cliente cuando se genera un click, es decir no debo ir al cs para mostrar una ventana ni mucho menos al server

Comment: ¿ que version de bootstrap tienes ?

Comment: Nugget boostrap 4.5

Answer (score 0):

Bueno finalmente fue un error propio! al parecer la letra del mensaje que estaba contenido en el modal tenia color blanco lo cual no contrastaba con el fondo del mismo modal.

Lo solucione colocando un color al mensaje!

```
<div class="modal-body" ><p **style="color:black"**>¿Desea eliminar el registro?</p></div>
```